# React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: reactjs

Routing using useLocation in react v6 and the error message says React Hook "useLocation" cannot be called inside a callback.
This was not an issue in v5 so just asking advice on how this can be solved.

```
const Loadable = (Component) => (props) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const isDashboard = pathname.includes("/dashboard");

  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <LoadingScreen
          sx={{
            ...(!isDashboard && {
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              width: 1,
              zIndex: 9999,
              position: "fixed",
            }),
          }}
        />
      }
    >
      <Component {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

Comment: Loadable is not a function component. "React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Loadable` generates a react component but you [cannot call a react hook outside of a react component](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) (or another hook), so this pattern won't quite work.

You could potentially solve this by making `Loadable` a component and rendering the `Component` as a child.

Something like this:

```
const Loadable = ({children}) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const isDashboard = pathname.includes("/dashboard");

  return (
    <Suspense
      fallback={
        <LoadingScreen
          sx={{
            ...(!isDashboard && {
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              width: 1,
              zIndex: 9999,
              position: "fixed",
            }),
          }}
        />
      }
    >
      {children}
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
<Loadable>
    <Component  /> // You can add any props directly to the child here
</Loadable>
```